# Getting error while executing stuff on inner joined table

Tags: .net, sql-server

```
select
   distinct  
    stuff((
        select ',' + (select b.name from Department a inner join Names b on b.ID= a.ID).name
        from (select a.ID from Department a inner join Names b on b.ID= a.ID) asd
        where asd.ID= (select a.ID from Department a inner join Names b on b.ID= a.ID).ID
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as Namessss
from (select b.*,a.* from Department a inner join Names b on b.ID= a.ID) as NAM
```

I was trying to take the string corresponding to ID's from another table. I used to inner join those 2 tables and tried to stuff them using a comma-separated. I executed this and an error popped up.

> Cannot call methods on int.

was the error message.

Comment: Answer has already been given, I'll just want to point out that if you are on Sql Server 2017 or later, you can use STRING_AGG instead of STUFF. Performances are a lot better. Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
select
       distinct  
        stuff((
            select ',' + (select b.name from Department a inner join Names b on b.ID= a.ID).name
            from (select a.*,b.* from Department a inner join Names b on b.ID= a.ID) asd
            where asd.ID= NAM.ID
            for xml path('')
        ),1,1,'') as Namessss
    from (select a.*,b.* from Department a inner join Names b on b.ID= a.ID) as NAM
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
 asd.RepositoryID = (select a.RepositoryID from tblAwardDelDataPlanRepoDtls a inner join tblRepository b on b.ID= a.RepositoryID).RepositoryID
```

You should change to

```
 where asd.RepositoryID in (select a.RepositoryID from tblAwardDelDataPlanRepoDtls a inner join tblRepository b on b.ID= a.RepositoryID)
```

or

```
 where asd.RepositoryID = (select top 1 a.RepositoryID from tblAwardDelDataPlanRepoDtls a inner join tblRepository b on b.ID= a.RepositoryID)
```